# EF Core with SQLite, Code First, case insensitive Contains for one column, sensitive for other

Tags: sqlite, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, matching, case-sensitive

I have EF Core 1.1.0 preview with SQLite database and code-first approach. I have two strings in the table A and B. I have checked that if I have

```
IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
query = query.Where(i => i.A.Contains(pattern));
```

the matching is case sensitive. That is what I need for string A, but when I want to query about string B, I would like to specify case insensitive matching.

Is it possible?

My current workaround is using ToLower:

```
query = query.Where(i => i.B.ToLower().Contains(pattern.ToLower()));
```

this works well, but I'm not sure it is the best solution.

In my OnModelCreating override, I have tried to use

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<E>().Property(i => i.B).HasAnnotation("CaseSensitive", false);
```

but this had no effect and the matching (without using ToLower) was still case sensitive.

Is there any way to say that this B string inside the entity should be always compared case insensitively (i.e. operations like ==, Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith)?

From the logs, I can see the query translates to

```
    SELECT ...
    FROM ... AS "i"
    WHERE ((instr("i"."B", @__pattern_0) > 0) OR (@__pattern_0 = ''))
```

Comment: Same issue here ;(

Comment: End of March and this is still an issue with version 1.1.1 ! Have you found any tricks to this issue (Except writing the sql query yourself that is :)) ?

Comment: I'm using i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(something) and it works for me, so I made no progress in this research and just use it, so no news here from me

Comment: It seems,EF Core team doesn't have immediate plans to support unified case comparisons https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8033#issuecomment-290864336 , https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9126